# How do I customise my section numbering to start from 2.1?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

So these sections are to occur at the same level using only `\section`.
Except section numbering will start from 1, and go to 2, 3, 4... etc. which is not what I want.  What I was is:

> 2.1 Summary
>   2.2 Inventors
>   2.3 Innovation
>   2.4 World Patent Coverage
>   2.5 Advantages
>   2.6 Limitations
>   2.7 Patent Challenges
>   2.8 Market applications and opportunities
>   2.9 Exploitation
>   2.10 Clinical Trials
>   2.11 References

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\date{April 1, 2012}
\begin{document}
\title{Patrys}
\maketitle

\section{Summary}
\section{Inventors}
\section{Innovation}
\section{World Patent Coverage}
\section{Advantages}
\section{Limitations}
\section{Advantages}
\section{Patent Challenges}
\section{Market Applications and Opportunities}
\section{Exploitation}
\section{Clinical Trials}
\section{References}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{2.\arabic{section}}
```

to your preamble.

Comment: Brilliant Alan, worked like a charm.  Thanks!